# mongo native ensureIndex does not create index

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using the mongodb native driver for node. I call `ensureIndex({ keywords: 1})` after retrieving the collection. When I check in the mongo console, nothing appears when I call `db.mycol.getIndexes()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can add the text as an answer below. That’s the stack-overflow-way, just answer your questions like others would. After two days (if not better answer arrives) you can even accept your own answer as correct. It’s better when other people see your question has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

The API docs helped a little: http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#ensureindex

You're supposed to call ensureIndex on the database object, not the collection. This contradicts the JavaScript console.

Comment: Not sure if this has changed but `collection.ensureIndex` does appear to work for me locally. The code example [here](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#ensureindex) uses `collection.ensureIndex`.

Comment: For some reason, `collection.ensureIndex(...)` neither creates the index nor runs the callback for me, but `db.ensureIndex(collection, ...)` does. Using MongoDB 2.4.10, node-mongodb-native 1.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem and the problem was I was not opening the database before calling ensureIndex. What I was doing was (coffee script)

```
db.collection('resources').ensureIndex {"$**": "text"}, {name: "email_index_text"},(err, indexName) ->
        console.log indexName
        console.log err
        db.close()
```

and what worked was

```
db.open (err,database) ->
    db.collection('resources').ensureIndex {"$**": "text"}, {name: "email_index_text"},(err, indexName) ->
        console.log indexName
        console.log err
        db.close()
```

The first snippet did nothing at all. No index was created and no error thrown.